# Como trabalhar com ngIF do Angular com resolução de tela?

Tags: angular

Veja logo abaixo como fica a página Web;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora observe a tela com resolução abaixo de 992px

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso acontece por causa da coluna css

Eu gostaria de tirar essa coluna quando atingisse menos de 992px com ngIF do angular, é possível ? 
Se for possível como devo fazer?

Esse aqui é código?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="ui-g">
        <div class="ui-g-12  ui-lg-3"></div>
        <div class="ui-g-12  ui-lg-3 conheca_projeto"><h1><p>CONHEÇA</p>  O PRJETO</h1></div>
        <div class="ui-g-2  ui-lg-2">
            <div class="seta_topo animated  fadeInDown">
                <img src="assets/img/seta.JPG" height="250" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-g-12  ui-lg-4  seja_doador">
                <h1>SEJA UM DOADOR</h1>
            </div>
        <div class="ui-g-12  ui-lg-3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: E se ela fosse ocultada utilizando Media Queries com CSS?

Comment: Realizar essa implementação somente fará desaparecer da tela, porém não irá tirar o componente e ngIF atuar em cima do componente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pegando width onInit

```
public innerWidth: any;
ngOnInit() {
    this.innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
}
```

Pra manter atualizado no resize.

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize(event) {
  this.innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
}
```

Html

```
<div *ngIf="innerWidth > algumNumero">
```

Comment: acabei de ver agora sua postagem, ainda vou testar, mas não consigo entender que essa sugestão funcione porque nela não existe fixação do tamanho da resolução para ele ser executado, mas é como tinha dito antes, eu ainda não testei.

Comment: Funcionou cara, tu é fera hahaha, muito obrigado

Comment: valeu man, funcionou redondinho aqui...

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia retirar o componente utilizando media queries.

Caso sirva para você, é possível fazer desta forma:

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
   .conheca_projeto{  display: none ; } 
 }
```

Comment: Eu não tive sucesso com essa sugestão   :(

Comment: especificamente qual foi o problema?

Comment: Gostaria que a acoluna que se encontra a imagem seta fosse retirada quando atingisse 992 px, se não entender eu explico novamente sem problema.

Comment: Sim, eu entendi. Teoricamente essa media querie que eu passei resolveria. 
Tu consegue aplicar ela e dar uma olhada no inspecionar elemento se o display dela ficou como none?