# Design responsivo em angular 2+

Tags: css, angular, layout-responsivo

É possível através do angular 2+ conseguir o tamanho e largura do navegador e a partir disso, enviar esses dados para o css de modo a deixar responsivo? Existe alguma outra forma de deixar responsivo sem media queries?

Sei que existe o seguinte decorator que consegue obter o tamanho e largura do navegador, mas existe alguma maneira de através destes valores deixar o design responsivo?

Grato

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
```

Comment: Veja que um "design responsivo" se consegue com `css`, e não com o *framework* `javascript` que esteja usando, seja `angular`, `react` ou qualquer outro, tendo que escrever código para fazer o o que o navegador já faz pra você usando `css`. Apenas pontuado isso, se ainda quiser fazer usando `javascript`, a própria linguagem consegue obter essa informação, o objeto `window.screen` retornar largura e altura. Além disso, você pode ter o tamanho da área efetivamente "usável" com `window.innerWidth` e `window.innerHeight`.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o media query no seu css normalmente. Se você quiser usar o ngIf para remover elementos do dom dinamicamente da uma olhada na minha reposta aqui [Como trabalhar com ngIF do Angular com resolução de tela?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/305498/como-trabalhar-com-ngif-do-angular-com-resolu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-tela/305988#305988)

Pegando width onInit

```
public innerWidth: any;
ngOnInit() {
    this.innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
}
```

Pra manter atualizado no resize.

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize(event) {
  this.innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
}
```

Html

```
<div *ngIf="innerWidth > algumNumero">
```